# R tictoc inside function

Tags: r

I would like to collect timings from different parts of a code in a log file by using the **tictoc** package in R. I wonder if it is possible to use tic()/toc() inside a function and collect the
times also there? The code I have in mind is as follows:

```
tic("Total time")

tic("time: 1")
A <- matrix(1.0, 5000, 5000)
toc(log = TRUE)

func1 <- function(B) {
tic("time: 2")
  r <- sum(B[1,])
toc(log = TRUE)
  return(r)
}

result <- func1(A)

toc(log = TRUE)
tic.log(format = TRUE)
```

Thank you

Comment: the log shows time 2 for me, what else were you expecting?

Comment: that's correct, I was writing the wrong name of the function func_1 instead. I couldn't see the statistics, Thanks!